# Аудиопоток в режиме реального времени (аналог радио) на Node.JS

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных

Возможно ли вообще на Node.JS сделать радио в режиме реального времени? Т.е. свой плейлист песен. Всё это дело объединяется в один аудиопоток и идет пользователям в режиме реального времени.

Можно ли это сделать без всяких ffmpeg и других C-библиотек? Средствами самого языка.

Я использовал fs.createReadStream и библиотеку Throttle (для ограничения байтов в секунду). Всё это дело работает, ноо... Главная проблема заключается в том, что в браузере по прямой ссылке это дело в первый раз очень долго загружается (буферизируется). Потом начинает играть, но со временем режим "реального времени" пропадает + на некоторых песнях трансляция резко затыкается. В чём может быть проблема?